# Why is this expression in my Angular app displaying the literal text rather than the result of the evaluated expression?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I am trying to figure out why a section of my Angular app is displaying - literally - 'zipcodeFilters.text', as opposed to the evaluated result of this.

The relevant view code I'm using here looks like this:

```
<filter-option name="Zipcode"
        placeholder="Enter ZIP Code"
        [usePlaceholder]="!zipcodeFilters.text"
        [visible]="zipcodeFilters.enabled">
    <filter-label>{{zipcodeFilters.text}}</filter-label>
    <filter-menu>
        <div class="visit-type-filter-options">
            <md-input-container [dividerColor]="color">
                <input mdInput placeholder="ZIP Code" 
                       value="zipcodeFilters.text" 
                       [(ngModel)]="zipcodeFilters.text" 
                       (keyup.enter)="filterByZip(zipcodeFilters.text)">
            </md-input-container>
            <button md-button class="reset-button" (click)="filterByZip(zipcodeFilters.text)">Filter</button>
            <button md-button class="reset-button" (click)="unfilterZipResults()">Reset</button>
        </div>
    </filter-menu>
</filter-option>
```

From the above section you'll see that:

```
    placeholder="Enter ZIP Code"
    [usePlaceholder]="!zipcodeFilters.text"
```

... is used to say, if there is no result of 'zipcodeFilters.text' (i.e., the user has inputed nothing) then use the placeholder, which is "Enter ZIP Code".

However, when I first load the component view, I don't see "Enter Zip Code" there, I see - literally - 'zipcodeFilters.text'.

If I delete that, then the filter shows the placeholder text as expected. However, upon refresh of the page, I'm back to seeing 'zipcodeFilters.text' rather than the placeholder text.

This relevant parts of the corresponding component look like this:

```
zipcodeFilters = {
    enabled: true,
    options: [

    ],
    text: null
};

public filterByZip(zip) {
    const arr: any = [];
    if (zip) {
      arr.push(zip);
    }
    const zipCall = this.zip = arr.length === 0 ? undefined : arr.toString().split(', ');
    const zipArr = Array.from(zipCall);
    this.sendZipcode.emit(zipArr);
}

unfilterZipResults() {
    this.sendZipcode.emit();
    const arr = [];
    this.zipcodeFilters.text = '';
}
```

What's making this display the literal text rather than the evaluated expression here?

Comment: did you see the `console`. It would have definitely logged errors

Comment: @Aravind, no errors in the console. And even stranger, this is working in another component, but not here. I have studied closely, but both look exactly the same.

Comment: @Muirik thanks for pointing that out, I misread the tags

Comment: @Muirik ok. Can you elaborate in plunkers with both the code.

Comment: Not familiar with setting up plunker examples.

Comment: I'm no sure if this is your problem, but i see on your input that you have this value="zipcodeFilters.text" immediately preceding the [(ngModel)]="zipcodeFilters.text". You should not have both of these

Comment: There's no string interpolation going on here. There's expression parsing.

Comment: can you add code bits for `filter-label` component.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

value="zipcodeFilters.text"  Remove this portion.. it should work